# cimg and GraphicsMagick momentarily opens windows console

Tags: c++, qt, graphicsmagick, cimg

I have a program that iterates through a folder of images and processes them using CImg. The GraphicsMagick library allows me to open .png files. I'm working within QT if that affects anything

When I run the program, the console opens briefly, for the duration of one line of code,

```
 CImg<unsigned char> image(img_to_be_read.c_str());
```

The title of the console window is C:\System32\cmd.exe, and as far as I can tell, nothing is displayed inside the window. And because it is opening and closing on every iteration, it essentially locks up my computer for the duration it runs. I'd rather not have to dig around inside of CImg or GraphicsMagick to fix this, so is there an easy way to either hold the console window open or suppress it entirely?